# Visualization using Parallel methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

I am using the Parallel.Foreach loop to issue requests in parallel. I wanted to know if there was a way to see visually what is happening behind the scenes when these requests are issued? ( A way to see that they are actually being issued in parallel).

I am using VS 2010

Comment: remember that the TaskPrallelLibrary is rather intelligent. If it determines that a set of tasks would gain little or no benefit
by running in parallel, it will opt to perform them in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some test prints in each requests.

Something like...

```
Console.WriteLine("Start request.");
Console.WriteLine("Processing XXX");
Console.WriteLine("Finishing request.");
```

This way you can see the outputs while the program is running.
You can also print out timestamps is desired.